# cgi problem command line ok but 403 on website

Tags: apache2, 403-forbidden, fastcgi

I am running on Debian 9 strech, hello.cgi

on command line

```
perl -cTw hello.cgi
```

all is fine

When i try to navigate to the subdirectory I get an error 403.

I add some lines to apache2.conf to execute CGI to a special directory.

```
<Directory "/var/www/special-directory/">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

I put permission to hello.cgi

```
chmod 755 hello.cgi
```

I don't know why?

Comment: Have you tried `chown username:usergroup -R /var/www/`

Comment: yes i try. There is a index.html in the same directory and it works.